# How to display sqlite contents

Tags: android

I'm not that experienced so I may have missed something obvious. What I am trying to achieve is a search feature for the database.

The two methods I'm thinking of are either an edittext and a listview and everytime the edittext changed a query is run and the listview is updated. Or populating the listview with all the data and then filtering it.

If I went for the second option I'm guessing it is less demanding on memory plus could I hide all the contents while the edittext is empty?

Any examples of implementation would be helpful too.

Thanks

Comment: sqlite is a very simple (and very cool) database, you get things in and out using sql calls

Comment: Thanks IanNorton, although I did know this already. I should have specified im not that experienced with doing this particular process I want to achieve in Android, but the overall concept I have worked with in other languages and ways before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start is the [Android Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) under the [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) section. Have a look at the [Searchable Dictionary sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html) there.